# How to call a hub method from c#

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm trying to do a small signalR sample to understand it. But i got stuck and not able to get the output.

Here is my sample code

```
public class HubClass : Hub
{
    public void HubMethod(string myMessage)
    {
        Clients.All.hubClient(myMessage);
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubClass>();
    hubContext.Clients.All.HubMethod("Hello");
    return View();
}

<div class="msg"></div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    var hubCls = $.connection.hubClass;
    $.connection.hub.start();
    hubCls.client.hubMethod = function (message) {
        $('.msg').text(message);
    };
</script>
```

I don't know where I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

In your hub you need to call the method you want invoked on the clients, ie

```
   Clients.All.HubMethod(myMessage);
```

SingalR will convert the method name to camel case and call the `hubMethod` function on the browser.

You also need to add an Owin startup class that enables SignalR in your site. This is described in [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR2 and MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)

Comment: If i add this `Clients.All.HubMethod(myMessage);` to my hub method and then this as @jerry said `hubCls.server.hubMethod("some message");` to my script, i'm getting output. But i want to call it from c# like `hubContext.Clients.All.HubMethod("Hello1");hubContext.Clients.All.HubMethod("Hello2");`